# Enable Rails SQL caching in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to enable the [Rails SQL cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) in a rake task.

The [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) sais:

> If Rails encounters the same query again for that request, it will use the cached result

I want to achieve the same for a rake task. If I do the same query multiple times, I want it to use the previous one.

Is there any way to use that feature, or do I have to implement [Low-Level Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can enable the cache in a block http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-cache

```
task your_rake_task: :environment do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.cache do
    # should cache queries inside the block
  end
end
```